# How can I get the value of this: product of (36^20-10000-i)/(36^20-i) when 0<i<10000?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, octave, probability

I have to solve this: 
www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+(36^20-10000-i)%2F(36^20-i)%2C+i%3D0+to+1000000 
, but the precision and computing time isn't enough. The best what I can solve is something like this: www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+(36^5-10000-i)%2F(36^5-i)%2C+i%3D0+to+10000. I tried octave, but I'm newbie - the precision is bad.

The real problem behind the scenes:
I have a folder, with 10k files. The filename length is 20. The filename can contain uppercase char and number (thats 36). If I guess the filenames randomly (but never the same filename), what is the probability, that I dont hit any of the files after 1 million tries? (I know the file length is 20 and the used chars set)

Comment: This is 1 - (probability that *none* are correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i and even 10000+i are very small against 36^20=1.33674945388437e+31, even for i=10^6,

```
(36^20-10000-i)/(36^20-i)
=
(1-36^(-20)*(10000+i))/(1-36^(-20)*i)
```

is approximatively

```
1-36^(-20)*(10000+i-i)-36^(-40)*((10000+i)*i+i*i)
```

so the product for 10000 trials is

```
(1-36^(-20)*10000)^10000-(1-36^(-20)*10000)^9999*36^(-40)*10000^3
```

and the first term is about

```
exp(-36^(-20)*10^8) approx 1-7.48083342838978e-24,
```

the second is smaller `36^(-20)*10^8*(36^(-20)*10^4)`, and thus very small against the difference of 1 and the first term.

So the probability to hit an existing name is about `7.5*10^(-24)`.

For one million trials, nothing fundamental changes, only the power goes from 10^4 to 10^6 in

```
(1-36^(-20)*10000)^(10^6) approx 1-7.5*10^(-22)
```

so the probability to hit an existing filename is 100 times greater, but still essentially zero.

(enter Dr. Evil mode "one hundred billion ...")

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:  Simplify.  When you're dividing a base to two different exponents, it's equal to the base raised to the difference of the exponents.

36^((20-10000-i)-(20-i)) = 36^(20-10000-i-20+i) = 36^10000

Step 1.5:  Are you sure you're doing this right...?

Step 2:  Realize this is going to be an enormous number, thousands of digits long.

Step 3:  Use [bc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language)

`$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type 'warranty'. 
36 ^ 10000
10592724396465553293085964452355445372969547823180171662872578059926\
96965911156849726207995688696363971580116588495264745415705767590893\
59900510534469588593053483482165044260338330279081478644076100645786\
99518840101487576866246095691788864386117382025967878499058855300489\
50946198489642917381262139909472914651440633506677357537369688375760\
90809440854763075012377414728771166205920636516277274073378199983331\
21444724275689426565782276032900420128046178416657151304900957497113\
51003984733153614959228590178788289544944296012159503030481409860125\
33716728092552367945381750481571255339264340936778611288799019269907\
39772516413442059762468001101693542210768066860298995372410073656878\
94289388087465159162077915079035608496531563838174605404321056838673\
52441003169720358821279147737643966950348948520149730835050332123606\
89212671641622293458295380143404774948380239883913431139871662869494\
95290213986738670843442524426623450403597181001293133499452545401820\
17262290776738798005327671960325012046990733842023592947435406895184\
07815980826485476732355209038460322004708884531310406332474490804778\
64204725680450234083427792775954133354328642751589614917084081472964\
30063919512934808668915373335047810847896652626741635465735307411093\
09248374332108959843325665728646081775081004611996518733703528436832\
87343198060662488623297128466146285053625407691961243679126688490501\
26173810509771787526942174139897963785480857355467755075823511068516\
19123453273441830897208890719301609708533455548147471134684407022646\
77837849922614701739362575811233937121473889442501732850475984131074\
21114019737821498890616338768204598344961798534009367698642682988704\
16964659113881270767876908447164491216660728471246068179473179290926\
53753940210265469450107856835628576809195867931822620898576362380959\
79811398872111906947849882882856758531688152228108651632627992998593\
47223966318806868814438523728163188406589912297750361695559443822343\
37067366105854365542370272400805664750964150758142996084854197451796\
03548519965249252394087402450556263884832489496207206838873868857399\
71258741971109839078626760253904250006111155245664463774582816484684\
63400226991785916989854747468535631241108531664255041599839752666294\
56133982123521178895752965516293160690140818004784374285782408712469\
54585840576657719294652554027701618393948299092685297407227531005392\
44136753953436752789396632926027172964423016766745569044080448944185\
09662376943457869533302845153322126643106635172663023070693594715984\
31724793172619932441551956176171732915113474684456206521846432798526\
09254763456220355161512305176683650500195733410760018080454692563986\
84860774050448534202384117470698549816646402867793210944955991954392\
91722473644586861426020074310599506467652233294951378820107072683010\
76435958492852576173332346352189973765310198395976176326452261843160\
80148026925354650701804978604996448356399698684699393833963795882606\
79284346670836258720490922109985220476393408343042807081948760410036\
73678552136599550920755387932606881570043110023341156159298187164621\
74842498276859940148561646737268550117802886031885759279336154407130\
40199998475047937086487952541092607974273669600977885264062013384585\
60312894079779502818429474594396899411162889037130293221971001344199\
57662859074190586262682709089801277674302972657717180512574487476375\
80994303339933384280671262475655135369506440889954894936645055133396\
04971480762876995822403308842668486240929103882378516037251122089981\
61249774516540323592368086295637896140801827763454850565169652630581\
56564425766032348264975487224260809625939782814597163718919732113352\
54578030181570534443470425556949981715500693522750384226768556933499\
49435817245205007794674083355182585197479738189251213260308094796246\
30544086029335471680163883480696301374560280547080159244636863977942\
34255666120128428779314839993192068840831717567852927924750254908924\
80235513895944597147656119157630296038394351287685501450426411433513\
90333561621235113193415832258840004435880998570844577577719494374906\
86865410267396224917712428470751764331416807484911412609171386758086\
67509694075757311732905653891462991205048067414481346484032618047696\
56176718125419217359165790771186522894378891669629142249673170937737\
51669923940500459381461811904679450756904652789903853315824772924464\
07586000184628778892765093959627396611710511603101300097267121006070\
19037168076882441146900024504164643115754041237858914217956591400428\
14467164942117593151622872084092991344244301573658944062350801861474\
96506818748733120914404220597893803307249931687086305562201948123352\
19013931826817742177890492972010613465940416265721821517304639423797\
83129414812517711573440735179526091508051887322618873723396313733004\
17472101266008105069867014946809105507231545076197631224188091332456\
85494088517409107101567716960563001814316420587665765052683848597425\
81606277573175472898591926920326277548603068631324433589179866919418\
36874547290421606040529720204948400492386733174781990394338080787559\
98325330078787388399464698713712846740142188786396387696120895799228\
82149743850419539967091428320428137701996653506791586726040041552042\
00164477040306205624725154712925597908895979089038543917806090126636\
49286952224289736664281572387818066756135750204986843426310840867953\
08244576344152481908380892823424714641838638205136270794218799662318\
02312538016377619427724632815335868118416354770438998955854349671358\
34145335459321914261321268649353889586599921061703279036490301734015\
75857430764891521822317463590163602136974458533417461530769605440486\
19156005631580767040142718793761745322846880168818051670012849374214\
67910825814171828104972853193262287243306804340454947714146714521911\
13602346295651754716969111471070278361740059601372353683507657976326\
44443711145007513849329101858958143786567531517590685469151484156959\
96912137396097141284956622360273186582615116898048553374372599349758\
43768899454973597534496137278250716698051359496585136596313413087485\
89198907910160363713445490366156021476879999625404274399638947258628\
19292167902372046012076775917786885230419063784381357367039430918083\
04988788382460260602071768816169165570659907030359246968435659363782\
45251729413267313116139930432655546022183957164703287368012116905745\
52695140205645562604071167842389257021594764165025083186272100946095\
89381432697549819299485316443138312071908859736798677765810586723434\
99658470099872030260776663357017095699639875038159921204762522112012\
70224041171484398234662775042239692298344964054231274075167487427687\
25801258757052371726391930399972818485280560800931024292462715894087\
36486777309273856997540889349306706064818578846306170015315861030258\
11677786336562917293543958637484515649414498384310517523037198319615\
57534396344917429451181994240791078967381960558768132745618282625660\
90785276728272093095015337724093281375722296016206787820771538207642\
53071848145272761680716125401409721562164153732503096808454337779056\
76756424827810623113750975599561642475316577612207869427294216416433\
90033975202122888045635520700190355748641461994576715227564547337455\
76727882392881391550825367242829434940904083110243675282922051863910\
85448557563169533219573765976474422602096118304954935470955805881587\
47106158031536127606457197472160340824946689761463632693449764672649\
04915606062134932760210249883202666439500845359706374058134200230898\
12889755931913455616027074354679029874000514981266148322307978807186\
77823559657108447188633027870165615153863839951694439399890764197075\
42521194327906278620400505048337449007325111689476086148785202727165\
15602863704969431988844410540131734553303910644298703394123062026517\
21321559550442576160479071737329771081335125291424234784133267496330\
35114037702071414202303080283587447856140360596721983204410842769678\
41549790342335100169665209438669121051711487205950160390767880407555\
01819886988018242088933477682997127986448980898936381418582161494234\
70582314802040717267946195408678236312795834495185035636045460961012\
14900239125200771946401472949036272204107043380890850080775721046035\
79340956543404075042033018733104228911171456011370593134686342699687\
63888857280243458058347567045863669245250925643557243286388972298132\
32016447430896577834331840573110013441406712695106001159379217144307\
27634991676472550745763857622080063554309599806975384120057774620700\
19821456068398358384213707715014484595413708214263182709404085183862\
84249012022046073525893904084860562562551872792193344042745306368127\
24031208834081135667460055605789484356810898711121572634639484541972\
35776517354621529231821522641110014957749314852732683216297297572985\
07505549131333908623998794654087769704320554463599751878882539607065\
70205070472068447798490399438967300018714192096990682920697144890230\
08418378555118804560893364696255249665357198904477225095365677208064\
55820243385970277952346346984418936816616927891637344815984463042630\
76929192247760457616259934821895211246688284028434467528292387292269\
61008116833909513747078992305708257055230791376350073260937402377382\
93199821488586819677747386920318928395493914745195682537290193930027\
95920610914952871903102416469569231594739343523860212988199812033319\
34274853337656960892656141336883200045770857884889004923388868840455\
67475180430839563156250199364560005819107646040331772452518181081560\
40567282891453104368902289436128561593891846423981522708502059086937\
80767168552502843682318129675623315654799318713113471462774667295589\
55478109142198455694260570772017903895032691742644617842061261512228\
17496984121425845593097876747500000896350847962823658432533892429692\
25349721716148552065897322706831397144054574043029104502315389368599\
38721093983715389459028016415122092283280489516339731008392195098479\
50023210728363291982514479347998408261634962058160387942424752362447\
76773211783656961717046973033866178128314056451468303051981228037639\
35271921765070805756965588639498380457036634198040221961237588598345\
31579956309613186832074613428420644253351086584569300437065464275201\
27309376738114186278437254335828256066824346541163130634115023467788\
58976637410777419919961873322787769792060768407763048615110878623880\
97915065846627224448774351049705849745463144103380379043372662745480\
17364084394145599580258842129432311341470748494266869639444789443367\
46995010158408457460194724161594045167887473956033680511170903571004\
13828560097835225247400499787631259727992706012426523905320809751984\
92550596319126488292801022213221860871125092665115835822215376993464\
36985953061005036810125924255692393773785146362251137203112425560043\
21220694275093259998206216244665259808607128127709254251105267819157\
24876524880477959973988344931418664629107455969275883517450236619675\
19909970846053080153329974043839853315391831622324148190306765801881\
47680540156503098091248094867009962416797626991602188144638560161122\
55526396274492637966932490900403111041864538884879861935139373716944\
81676653083165133769530661052690871112607693655310710109003013123608\
06572909177567626077267939276825693216864660497481268003082442496644\
17985431120565263665249374135767878094343818984126783502496841048531\
08497305398415036085821242994413180237403408769669912613368565097866\
05581247977918971942859737843550323282431233031628629451639765806865\
09744384816333238548436781826438628834399764250104133924447927137253\
13827310761991113410988948647822281327067208552174770882890792167868\
10034577717615770363921135450822946992866594105344623671790034485331\
97430071801783074648454387849184489935649322537738939361048200675874\
94291581315407063434780919933446824428534080015825042904903155265853\
79429475053780330688827677041047159659795296809733848901937867117403\
46031471050649694689551477170411875164170587523638687443594373618957\
15983142166332946057820517759736388035173704906538539015628611202572\
01790025211778031676784893084481047634903841950933371445596231678286\
89591442141608816660311489134115769154478400403524302196927588676245\
89430028766244884380392984005463729853876562602183160740649816144985\
67428138979390777313865011304035553656715756782239075085902454332775\
50351757358265499657079170476759072984991824841374177877847287525866\
50129475794909572490758834118568686590292882069896523841347169545872\
70076343995187534074477042611974105066487757756177953407618365213305\
86413993994576598683006510468733839687060971772864045546649337478994\
23083060632294502212599750859056417367356191744560085653085517103243\
96824783829185340999261754709574456735530919338719015941407596941598\
99593032437074680064401854056560817228764314319027703935695744892748\
24898423274332823790584968728779966351745394831631345084582512446186\
46769185419002312352841602438036567930096964216360732797580673745550\
00480647999979963788053018885460749951655871215383379538703892643881\
39396382964363370588383792276463404004445321486691376627739792159717\
88002344966726140135670367927342989576027415657841531123266095983543\
96992372541367313866392399569837183874633769600879163141380668441967\
04413121644527264878276892839489690261373869027654353645522203326921\
66631948200719438281124876158323400066191593006770458651049588422323\
14250898798281647316239746443304389131907018760693562525297296830814\
54093797459690146074556895402411502357986402965065988304516182203140\
71230346071282215620349440290186317240947960340799647807498036485168\
21828740936280733194896533090435412973143050238839473079030288519001\
04956062142708971413253251707808833734288541044786039255581803382825\
44633893652319221803856742291850901900695918407714701307300531918398\
65994676056810057621085233857787541973993754422331768782069962088209\
01979211433114275083440655570545025984793903365896477194157465933820\
16971445403969503023718089776726575731213280700946319104887528563409\
24393857692631684650129370176580574535573731991613379128250606531163\
98339548698002841552091128798745996101478536813498098761335154630828\
03472029300568934688988240184297641635074086008428652924089094355132\
74158350650635994357008023991220503165305293939298726905802670953959\
74687317661778641839126202159986275882937302937908530970607239009849\
23848115874701136100065494691978095705876879069486829768289888882975\
98998377203165430037994150935771185648572459615886679622356334448159\
96925224960244983155537376593984669583296143308310314704959395448411\
71978896821615782548214650116327904414112227988046322553245265021790\
69542321909579306907013771210805883803953587012737658451439458883263\
87640981171512065387314808093618502579610340906202311933906767822485\
94504249150445722433272564349098788322464892911136918025312169992850\
67514006779842500541688184888417085127659053403960061409252790409108\
93814863818951222845131127137831138422980630936661364749536354430129\
65886009787050382438691041024619242556997677945815375701911984739809\
15100479866087593224710715530390668549022881089423988622013431572603\
59238334920325468012737729213502313337508873289445003080471754192008\
03750514239014954575745629288564264490198803082622812461013998601043\
58208804373815976132017266037606373897266974996771935882580861385983\
62463674265103066800129498303951212409554057591321675481737669495462\
17347010862766598798694599810891054000903708859645901121958786977860\
42617558214916148167530305325679160902935806974747716225885181333708\
44750017393892649664686087678152934636861073335069008529000881685462\
71976547782910581539362973082619632714447642571084003324070083455631\
57763298170442755089939490660691771447337511691584803646413509830863\
54401022591001105987140738285441702444087463818234694891791196099435\
74471449996668489274742548359428935868012179561933913150380861280429\
30326802425977142091654193356989661935324429921190499181786509003404\
01596989165831248551581989990716614080948264090885901424420205462365\
89215453479632192544710026261032889069381981077024032140011643905343\
891534124566431071042824673625295228660308296372490260709376`

Step 4:  Ouch.  Thousands of digits, though.

Comment: Thats correct, but you use wrong formula at step 1: (36^(20-10000-i))/(36^(20-i)), the question is this: ((36^20)-10000-i)/((36^20)-i)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to evaluate this formula,

```
((N - m)! * (N - k)!) / ((N - m - k)! * N!)
```

where N = 36^20, m = 10^6, k = 10^4, and the notation `x!` means "the factorial of `x`".

Because you are taking factorials of such large numbers (all of the same order of magnitude as 36^20), Stirling's approximation -- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html -- will be very accurate, and in your calculation you will be able to cancel out many of the terms, resulting in four terms that look like n^(n+1/2), which you can then reduce to three terms that look like p^(n+1/2) where p is very close to 1 and n is very large.  I think in fact the base numbers are so close to 1 that you might use the approximation x for ln(1+x). (A closer approximation of ln(1+x) is possible by taking additional terms from the series ln(1+x) = x - (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3 - (x^4)/4 + ... .)

This might be a good question for https://math.stackexchange.com/, as it seems the first thing you need to do is to find a more easily computed formula than you have.

Comment: This would apply if the number of trials were to reach numbers that even Dr. Evil could not imagine. To get into the range of a hit probability of 1%, one would need about 10^25 trials, where then the Stirling approximations would give better probabilities than the approximation by a Poisson process.

Comment: The smallest factorial in the formula above is (36^20 - 1010000)!.  To within, say, three orders of magnitude, what do you think the relative error is in Stirling's approximation for that quantity? (Try formula (26) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html ...)

Comment: The question is: When selecting k elements of a set of N, what is the probability of avoiding a given set of m elements? So the formula is (N-m choose k)/(N choose k) = (N-m)!/((N-m-k)!*k!) * ((N-k)!*k!)/N! = ((N-m)!*(N-k)!)/((N-m-k)!*N!), which is indeed the formula you read off the description. m is smaller than k, so one should pair the factorials that are m apart and cancel common terms, giving ((N-k)(N-k-1)...(N-k-m+1))/(N(N-1)...(N-m+1))=(1-k/N)(1-k/(N-1))(1-k/(N-2))...(1-k/(N-m+1)). Since N is very large against m and k, this is approximately (1-k/(N-m/2))^m approx 1-(k*m)/N.

Comment: Ah, you mean you don't _need_ Stirling's approximation to solve this problem.  In fact both ways come out very close to 1-(k*m)/N in the end.